# I have locked myself out of my Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: locked-out

How can I get my Samsung Galaxy S5 unlocked without having to do a factory reset?  The phone is asking me to enter a back up pin number,  but I don't know what that is. I have tried EVERY password that I thought we set up on this phone but now it says that I only have 1 more try b4 it will factory reset and erase all my info....Please, HELP!!

Comment: Hmm. Did you install a custom recovery, and is your device rooted?

Comment: While waiting for answers, please check our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info). This will at least get you familiarzed with the topic, if not even give a solution.

Comment: Lanette, is your device T-Mobile or international version? Tell us your model number? Recovery will not be easy on Verizon or AT&T versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way to remove the lock. While I don't own this particular phone, you can flash Aroma File Manager to the phone by copying a zip file containing the manager to your external SD card. Boot the device into recovery, and then install the package. Go into the system files of the phone. There is a file somewhere called password.key or pattern.key, depending on whether the lock is a pattern or pin/password. Delete it. If the system files are not showing up in Aroma, make sure the device has mounted the system files in options. Reboot, and the lock should be removed.

Comment: You need custom recovery.

Comment: No you don't. I did it on my last phone by simply installing using stock recovery.

Comment: Hmmmm, is it that easy? I would think then the device is way too unsecured to my liking. I might be wrong though. Because if simply by mounting the system and looking for a password.key and delete, then oooh, stealing phones will be that easy

Comment: Yes, it is that insecure. But the beauty of Android is that the insecurities result in flexibility, which paves the way for Google employees' trademark trait - creativity.